# Using a batch file to send the TAB key and enter password

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that opens an exe program on my pc like so:

```
PING -n 2 localhost >nul
start "anything here" "C:\Program Files (x86)\myfolder\myprogram.exe"
```

This opens a form with an area to enter my password (username is already there as it has a "remember me" box), but the cursor is active in the username field, so when it opens I need to:

1. Hit the TAB key once to go to the password box
2. Enter my password
3. Hit the TAB key again TWICE to go to the login box
4. Press the ENTER key once to login

I have only had basic experience opening programs via batch files, so I am unsure how to proceed with the above.

Comment: Windows .bat files cannot interact with Graphical User Interfaces.  Pick a different scripting language.

Comment: @Squashman - I will take note of that. Any scripting language you would suggest for this kind of task?

Comment: I suggest the auth-window is the GUI-presentation of Windows UAC. UAC provides Windows security. Such way to increase privilege is insecure. You have to get some tricks to solve the task. UAC window interaction has special scheme. It use other security context (instead of standard user).